# How to make the x-axis start from zero in chartjs-plugin-streaming?

Tags: chart.js

I'm working on a project that could display sensing data on local web pages in real time with Django and I made this stream live data chart. But I don't need to this realtime x-axis ticks. I want to make the x-axis starting at zero and increasing 1 step by one second.

I think "xAxes type realtime" is the key, but I'm new to this and it's hard for me to solve alone, so I need your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00HC5.jpg)

```
<script>

  var chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
  };
  
  function onRefresh(chart) {
    var now = Date.now();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
      dataset.data.push({
        x: now,
        y: GetData()
      });
    });
  }

  var color = Chart.helpers.color;
  
  var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(100, 200, 200, 0)'
        ],
        borderColor: chartColors.blue,
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        borderDash: [8, 0],
        data: [],
        borderWidth:3,
        pointRadius:0,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      legend:{
        display:false
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Some Chart',
        fontSize:20,
        fontFamily:"Tahoma"
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks:{
            beginAtZero: true
          },
          gridLines:{
            display:true
          },
          type: 'realtime',
          display:true,
          position:'bottom',
          realtime: {
            duration: 20000,
            refresh: 1000,
            delay: 0,
            onRefresh: onRefresh
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          gridLines:{
            display:true
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'value'
          }
        }]
      },
    }
  };

  window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
  };
  
</script>
```

Is there any other way to make streaming live graph with Django, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself. The key was about 'xAxes ticks callback'. thank you.